# Laptop/Notebook PC for android

Tags: android

What should be a proper laptop for android development? My laptop isn't performing and I need my works done in a laptop or notebook pc. Please suggest me any model which fulfill the requirement or one step ahead of that. Thank you!

Comment: Lenovo ThinkPad W540

Comment: Primarily opinion based

Comment: Search for this on Quora, there's at least one question on this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The computer you pick must meet these requirements for the latest version of the Android Studio:

https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements

That is the only objective answer I can think of. Increasing the RAM above 2gb will improve your experience.